# MonoDevelop on Ubuntu builds forever

Tags: monodevelop

I'm having a strange issue with MonoDevelop on Ubuntu.

It's all been working OK for a while, but recently has stopped building anything. The solution was initially created in VS2013, but has worked for a while under MonoDevelop.
If I do a Clean, that works OK, with text in the Build output window.

If I Build, nothing appears in the Build output window and the "Building" message in the status bar at the top just rolls on for ever and ever:

[image]

I've stripped the sln right back to no projects and there is still a problem. 
I can't get rid of the rolling "Building" message: If I try a clean, it shows "Cleaning" for a moment (and does Clean), but then reverts to "Building" again, but nothing is built.

I can only get rid of the Building message by restarting MonoDevelop (and I can't build anything)

If I xbuild the solution from the command line, building is OK, so I am pretty sure it's a MonoDevelop issue.

I've just uninstalled an re-installed MonoDevelop with no success.

```
MonoDevelop- Version 5.10    
Mono 4.2.3 (64-bit)    
Ubuntu 14.04 x86-64
```

These are the two log entries that occur around the time the build starts

```
ERROR [2016-04-11 14:15:17Z]: Error while executing command: Build All
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject.OnGetItemFiles (Boolean includeReferencedFiles) <0x406984a0 + 0x000eb> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DefaultProjectServiceExtension.GetItemFiles (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem entry, Boolean includeReferencedFiles) <0x40687630 + 0x00020> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.GetItemFiles (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item, Boolean includeReferencedFiles) <0x406875f0 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.GetItemFiles (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item, Boolean includeReferencedFiles) <0x406875f0 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.GetItemFiles (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item, Boolean includeReferencedFiles) <0x406875f0 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.GetItemFiles (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item, Boolean includeReferencedFiles) <0x406875f0 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.GetItemFiles (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item, Boolean includeReferencedFiles) <0x406875f0 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem.GetItemFiles (Boolean includeReferencedFiles) <0x406869c0 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Solution.GetItemFiles (Boolean includeReferencedFiles) <0x4067e1b0 + 0x000a3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Workbench+<GetKnownFiles>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () <0x40960dc0 + 0x001ac> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) <0x40960980 + 0x00291> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Workbench.SaveFileStatus () <0x40960680 + 0x000b2> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Workbench.<Initialize>m__2 (System.Object , MonoDevelop.Projects.BuildEventArgs ) <0x40960650 + 0x0000f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.ProjectOperations.BeginBuild (IProgressMonitor monitor, ITimeTracker tt, Boolean isRebuilding) <0x4095fd40 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.ProjectOperations.Build (IBuildTarget entry, Boolean skipPrebuildCheck, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectOperationContext context) <0x4095d390 + 0x002cb> in <filename unknown>:0 
ERROR [2016-04-11 14:15:20Z]: GLib-Critical: Source ID 3728 was not found when attempting to remove it
Stack trace: 
  at GLib.ToggleRef.g_object_remove_toggle_ref (IntPtr , GLib.ToggleNotifyHandler , IntPtr ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.ToggleRef.Free () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Object.PerformQueuedUnrefs () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Timeout+TimeoutProxy.Handler () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gtk.Application.gtk_main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gtk.Application.Run () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Run () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main (System.String[] args, MonoDevelop.Ide.Extensions.IdeCustomizer customizer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any help / thoughts gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the startup item in the solution.userprefs:

```
<Properties StartupItem="MyProject/MyProject.csproj">
```

There was some issue with this project that caused the build to fail even when any other project was being built.
Glad that one's over.